# Get post values in controller in yii

Tags: yii

I have a function in controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
            $this->render('dashboard');
}
```

In dashboard page i have a form update

while trying to click button it goes to actionIndex.
I want to get  post values in update function .. how it will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `CActiveForm` in your update form. you can do in form update like this

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'my-form',
        'action'=>CController::createUrl('update')
)); ?>
```